# How to add a map created in QGIS to a Matlab plot

Tags: qgis, export, matlab

I am generating a number of plots in Matlab. I want to overlay these over maps I have created in QGIS. I thought the best way would be to import the maps as a geotiff into Matlab and then overlay my plots over the image. I have saved the project as an image, generating a tiff and a tiffw file.

I got stuck trying to import and display the tiff and tiffw file in Matlab. I am working with QGIS 2.10.1 and Matlab R2012b.

---

Here is what i have tried so far:

Matlab has a `geotiffread()` function to read geotiff files. Using this function to read the .tiff produces the following error.

> Error using geotiffinfo>readinfo (line 259) The file 'GeoTest.tiff'
>   does not contain any GeoTIFF Tags.  Use the function IMFINFO to obtain
>   information about the file.

I was able to import the .tiffw file into matlab using the code.

```
filename = 'GeoTest.tiff';
RGB = imread(filename);
worldFileName = getworldfilename(filename);
R = worldfileread(worldFileName, 'planar', size(RGB))
```

But still have to figure out how to put that into a figure together with my plot.

Comment: Hi Martin, can you elaborate on what "got stuck" means? Did you try something? Is there an error message?

Comment: I'll edit my question to elaborate a bit more. It was a combination of error messages and not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS, export the map as in image via 'save as image' in the file menu and choose 'tiff' as the file type. This will produce both a `.tiff` and a `.tiffw` file. The `.tiffw` file is known as a World File. As far as I can tell the `.tiff` file is not a GeoTiff file, or at least, Matlab does not recognise it as a GeoTiff file.

There seems to be an issue with the way QGIS generates its tiff files, to fix this do the following:

Open the file in an image processing program (I used ImageJ) and then save the file as a new tiff file.

In Matlab, use `mapshow()` to display the 'new' tiff file. Make sure the tiffw file is in the same directory.

```
mapshow('myMap.tiff')
ha = mapshow(X1,Y1,'DisplayType','point','Marker','s','MarkerEdgeColor','k')
hb = mapshow(X2,Y2,'DisplayType','point','Marker','o','MarkerEdgeColor','k')
legend([ha hb],'Stations', 'Assets');    
axis off
```